# show php code in echo

Tags: php

How do I print php code in a print / echo ?

What I mean is this:

```
<?php echo "<?php ?>"; ?>
```

Should output: `<?php ?>` on my screen, but I receive a blank page. Any special escaping that I have to use ?

Comment: Are you trying to make a **Quine**? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars('<?php ?>'); ?>
```

Comment: if you see the page, the <?php ?> was there, but the browser not render it as visual element because its for scripts, that's why you should out put it as entities.

Answer (score 2):

Akam's solution sorts out the PHP, if the Content-Type of the returned file is HTML.

Alternately, you could change the Content-Type to Text, thereby bypassing the HTML rendering.

```
<?php

header( 'Content-type: text/plain' );

echo '<?php ?>';

?>
```

Of course, this would affect the *whole* page, and not just a segment of it. As such, it would be useful it you were displaying the contents of a PHP script file as a standalone page, but if you were wanting to show snippets of PHP code within an HTML page, then Akam's solution would be better suited for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you print  and you pretend to see it as HTML, the browser will interprete the tag and show nothing, but you will still be able to see it if you look at the source code.
To show the < and > tags properly you should use &lt; and &gt; or use the [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) functions:

```
<?php
  echo htmlentities( '<?php ?>' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution built on [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) which accepts arrays for its parameters search and replace.

```
<?php
 echo str_replace(array('<','>'),array('&lt;','&gt;'),'<?php ?>');
?>
```

Check out the following demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3hp-itx